# JNI java to Cpp with short array

Tags: java, java-native-interface

My **Java** application needs to call **Cpp** library with **input** values to do calculation and then pass **result** back.

Because there are several **input** data: a `short[]`, few `int`s and `float`s, and the **output** contains two **`short[]`**, few `ints` and `float`s, I am think passing two Java objects, `inputObject` and `outputObject` to Cpp side. In Cpp side I call those `getXXX()` methods and `setXXX()` methods to get the input and get the output.

I know I need to `getMethodID` in Cpp side to call those **get** and **set** methods. But I cannot find any `CallShortArray()` available, like `CallIntMethod()` is for int.

Is there a way to do?

I can pass **individual** input parameters without above `inputObject` to get around the input data part. But for the ouput short[]s, I cannot find a way to do it without that `outputObject`.

Another question is about the **last** parameter of the **getMethodID** method. Is there document to tell me those **signature string** for **different** methods?

Comment: The signature document is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array is just an object.  So if you have a function which returns a `short[]`, you call it with `CallObjectMethod()` and get the result as a `jobject`, which you can then cast to a `jshortarray`.

For a description of how the last parameter (`sig`) to `GetMethodID()` works, see the description of [Type Signatures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/types.html#wp276).  You need to determine the type signature of each of the method's parameters and of its return value, then put them together appropriately.  For example, this method:

```
long f (int n, String s, int[] arr);
```

It has three arguments, which have these type signatures according to the table in the link above:

```
I                     (int)
Ljava/lang/String;    (java.lang.String)
[I                    (int[])
```

And it has a return type signature of `J` (for `long`).  So, putting that all together with the `"(" arg-types ")" ret-type` template, we can determine that the full signature is this:

```
(ILjava/lang/String;[I)J
```